# How can I find the aws instance I am being charged for?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My cost report shows charges

[image]

But I can't find what service or ec2 instances this means for the past 2-3 days and in the main two regions I use I have no running instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First click on 'Explore costs'.

[image]

This shows that in this case the cost is for a NAT instance.

It is still hard to find that NAT instance if it is not in the regions you generally use.
If you use the VPC service you can get an overall view of VPCs across regions and you get a sections that shows running instances:

[image]

### This is still confusing though as the VPC summary shows 0 running instances!

However if you open up the dropdown for 'See all regions' you can see there is actually one that is running:

[image]

### Clicking on that shows the culprit - a NAT instance running in Frankfurt !

[image]